# hasattr(value, "contribute_to_class") returns KeyError: 'contribute_to_class' (Django 4.1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, hasattr, django-4.1

A Django 1.1 / Python 2.7 project that I'm attempting to run on Python 3.10 / Django 4.1.

A Python related error (i.e. old import) or a django code error (i.e. missing field that's now mandatory) pops up, I fix it and rerun.

The current error, however, is coming from
`django/db/models/base.py`, from [this function](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/base.py#L85) -

```
def _has_contribute_to_class(value):
    # Only call contribute_to_class() if it's bound.
    return not inspect.isclass(value) and hasattr(value, "contribute_to_class")
```

I found this ticket -
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30309

that explains that `hasattr` is unreliable, but seems to be ignored.

Has anyone encountered this issue, and managed to find a solution other than staying on Django 1.1?

Comment: note, `hasattr` isn't unreliable, it just works *as one would expect*, i.e., not to silence anything but `AttributeErrors`, which is probably why that example wasn't removed

Comment: Shouldn't `hasattr()` return `True` or `False`, given an object and a string?

Comment: Not if retrieving the value raises an error that isn't an AttributeError. Just the same as if you did `try: obj.attr; return True except AttributeError: return False` if it was the same as a bare `except: return False` that would mask all sorts of things that are probably bugs and should error

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: it is interesting that value object you have. Value should be a Class. Can you give a little bit more information about Value. If there you override getaattribute dunder, i can imagine those behaviour

Comment: I won't do/recommend upgrading versions with a huge gap instead I would try to upgrade to the next possible version (or next possible LTS). Things may take more time - but, that's more reliable (from personal experience :wink)

Answer (score 1):

hasattr Python2 vs hasattr Python3.
They have different behavior

How works hasattr() in python 2:

```
try:
    getattr(foo, 'bar')
    return True
except:
    pass
return False #This is important part
```

How works hasattr() in python 3:

```
try:
    getattr(foo, 'bar')
    return True
except AttributeError as error:
    return False
raise AttributeError from error
```

It means - if you have any other problem in class - in python2 hasattr suppressed all.
But Python3 give you an AttributeError Exception.

That's why i ask you to give us the code of class of your "value".

By the way:
Django 4.1 call this method _has_contribute_to_class in ModelBase.
Django 1.xx don't have this method and don't call it.